# Does multiprocessing.shared_memory require locking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I'm learning about shared memory in Python, especially the python 3.8 module `multiprocessing.shared_memory`.  I see no mention of locking in the documentation.  (Although the parent module, `multiprocessing`, has a `Lock` object).  Are locks somehow handled in the underlying code of `multiprocessing.shared_memory` or in `/dev/shm`?  That is, is it safe to write to a `SharedMemory` object from multiple processes at the same time with no explicit locking?  Thank you advance for any clarification.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html

Answer (score -2):

[The Array() class](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/multiprocessing.Array) is supposed to be like the synchronized version of shared memory, so no I expect not. You get what it says: a block of shared memory with no synchronization overhead, for times when you don't need it or want to implement your own.

Comment: Your answer is more a guess than an answer to the question asked and more information could have been really helpful. For example, instead of a guess, you could have pointed to https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/multiprocessing/shared_memory.py#L49 and indicated that the methods used to create the shared memory are low-level functions and in the current implementation it does not look like there any synchronization primitives around the access of the shared memory

Comment: No, it is not a guess, that is the functionality, as implemented.

Comment: You are most likely right (see the link in my previous comment) but an answer to not be a guess needs proof. The proof can either be a link to the implementation or the documentation. For example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue does not seem to be synchronized if you only read the class documentation. However, someone could point to the main module description where this is written: `The Queue class in this module implements all the required locking semantics` to give a proper answer

Comment: I see. I am not a regular contributor to stack overflow, it was a casual answer, it was the correct one though. The docs are pretty clear, and I gave mention to the class which does provide locking.

Comment: I never said your expectation couldn't be right. However, if you look at the implementation of the SharedMemory (previous link) and the one of Array (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py#L84) you will see that the two do not share the same base. This makes your explanation using Array invalid. That's why, I recommended pointing towards the actual implementation of SharedMemory to explain why there is no locking on SharedMemory. And again, absence of mention of lock in the documentation is why the user asked the question, more explanation was expected.